# Storing functions within arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object-literal

I'm having a issue with something very simple. I am just wondering as to I can store these functions within an array. Check out some of the code below. I am unsure as to if this is correct as to how I am storing these functions. I am unsure as to if these functions should be within a object literal or array.This is not necessarily for a project, just good practice. Thanks!

```
//declaring a function 
function alert_name(){
    //declaring variables within a function asking user their name.
    var username =  prompt("Hey there, what is your name."," ");
//generating user input
    var chameleon = "Welcome " + username;
//combinators 
    //alert("Welcome " + chameleon+ ", This is 'the website");
};
// inserting quotes into a string that is being alerted from the browser.
function otherTHings(){
    var single = 'He said \'RUN\' ever so softly.';
    //alert(single);
};
//running these functions and actually carry out the operations 
//that have actually been declared into code above. 

//string operations
function string_opertaions(){
    var complete = "Com" + "plete";
    //alert(complete);
    // using combinators to do the same thing. 
    var sentance1 = "My name is";
    var sentance2 = "someone";
    var  totalsenatces = sentance1 += sentance2;
    //alert(totalsenatces);
};

//Booleans or true false values
function booleanys(){
    var lying = false;
    var truthful = true;
};
//Arrays very important. very similar to a object literal but different.
//Arrays store information or values or varibales/data. 
var rack = [];
rack[0] = alert_name();
rack[1] = otherTHings();
rack[2] = string_opertaions();
rack[3] = booleanys();
//alert_name();
//otherTHings();
//string_opertaions();
//booleanys();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the function and storing the result!

```
var rack = [];
rack[0] = alert_name;
rack[1] = otherTHings;
rack[2] = string_opertaions;
rack[3] = booleanys;
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks man. Ha, would you though recommend storing these functions within a object literal or would this practice be acceptable.

Comment: @blake it depends. are you going to need to run all of them with a loop?

Comment: The concept I had was basically having an array of functions for your arsenal essentially predefining all of your functions or as many as possible before the actual project had started to easy reference all the needed code. @Daniel A. White

Comment: @Blake no need to do that.

Comment: What is your suggestion for my desired outcome? @Daniel

Comment: So essentially if I was going to use an array to store these specific functions within a array it would need to be located before the functions were declared? @Daniel

Comment: This has given me the desired functionality I was looking for. Thank you for your insight as it is always helpful to get some advice especially when dealing with javascript. Thanks so much!